# document to find bugs fixed in cassandra 3.11.1?

Tags: cassandra

We have apache cassandra 3.11.0 installed i see new version 3.11.1 is installed can you guys point me to the document for the bugs fixed and if any new functionalities added in latest version

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CASSANDRA/versions/12341002 see Release Notes -> Improvement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3.11.1 has been released on 2017.10.10. You can check the [changes](https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob_plain;f=CHANGES.txt;hb=refs/tags/cassandra-3.11.1) and the [release notes](https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob_plain;f=NEWS.txt;hb=refs/tags/cassandra-3.11.1).